# Find out which endpoint sent a REST call

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to create a visualisation of REST calls among several internal and external services/servers. I'd like to know which endpoint called which other endpoint. I figured that the only way to do this is to do this on the caller side, because the receiver does not have any information about the caller endpoint.

Here's my thinking:

1. I create an object like RestTemplate and call the method.
2. I create an Interceptor or something like that, which will extract the information from the RestTemplate.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to find out which REST endpoint called the RestTemplate method. The RestTemplate (or other similar object) call could be called in nested methods, so for example the endpoint could invoke a private method, which then calls the external service itself.

Is there any way how to get this information? Or am I maybe just thinking too hard and there is an easier way to do this?

Example:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello() {
    methodThatCallsOtherEndpoint("something.com/weather"); // this method inside itself calls an endpoint
    logRestCall("localhost:8000/hello", "something.com/weather"); // how do I do this automatically without having to type it myself?

    return "hello";
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It sounds that what you're wanting is something like Zipkin.

Answer (score 0):

If these services/servers have a static IP you can possibly, tag them by their IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *[Spring Sleuth](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/)* to trace the relationship between different REST calls.

Comment: That looks very promising and I'll look into that. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick

```
@Slf4j
public class LogsInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final ThreadLocal<StopWatch> STOPWATCH = new ThreadLocal<>();
    protected static final String REQUEST_ID = "requestId";
    protected static final String REQUEST_URI = "requestUri";
    protected static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "requestMethod";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_TIME_MS = "responseTimeMs";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE = "responseStatusCode";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        try {
            StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
            STOPWATCH.set(sw);
            STOPWATCH.get().start();

            String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            MDC.put(REQUEST_ID, requestId);
            MDC.put(REQUEST_METHOD, httpRequest.getMethod());
            MDC.put(REQUEST_URI, httpRequest.getRequestURI());
            return true;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            STOPWATCH.remove();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, @Nullable Exception ex) {
        try {
            STOPWATCH.get().stop();
            long timeInMillis = STOPWATCH.get().getTotalTimeMillis();
            MDC.put(RESPONSE_TIME_MS, String.valueOf(timeInMillis));
            MDC.put(RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE, String.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
            log.info("Request: {} {} Time taken: {}ms Status: {}", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), timeInMillis, response.getStatus());
        } finally {
            MDC.clear();
            STOPWATCH.remove();
            log.debug("afterCompletion called");
        }
    }

    protected void startStopWatch() {
        STOPWATCH.set(new StopWatch());
    }
}
```

To explain as simply as I can, spring itself provides this interface to help you intercept execution of each thread, for whatever reason you want. In this case you just proceed to log basic info provided inside HttpServletRequest, without polluting your controller code.